Why does the Angular constructor run before ngOnChanges even though it's not a part of the lifecycle hooks?
I've noticed that in Angular, the constructor of a component runs before the ngOnChanges hook, despite the constructor not being considered a part of the lifecycle hooks. Could someone explain why this happens?
I've noticed that in Angular, the constructor of a component runs before the ngOnChanges hook, despite the constructor not being considered a part of the lifecycle hooks. Could someone explain why ?

The constructor is a JavaScript feature not an Agular feature. You could say that it is a JavaScript lifecycle hook which all of JavaScript and anything written in JavaScript inherit.

If you think about it, you won't even have a component if you don't call a constructor function. Unless the functions are static, in any language, you need to construct the class's object before using any of it's function. That's why constructor will always be the first function to get called.
